# How to encrypt data -> Assymmetric Encryption java

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

bouncycastle java - code ([original  code](https://github.com/kagkarlsson/cms-decrypt-example/blob/master/src/main/java/no/posten/dpost/EncryptAndDecrypt.java))

```
public class EncryptAndDecrypt {

private static final String WORK_DIR = "..\\dir\\";

private static final File SOURCE_PDF = new File(WORK_DIR, "input.txt");
private static final File DESTINATION_FILE = new File(WORK_DIR, "out.txt");
private static final File DECRYPTED_FILE = new File(WORK_DIR, "decrypted.pdf");

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (!new File(WORK_DIR).exists()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Update WORK_DIR to point to the directory the project is cloned into.");
    }
    Files.deleteIfExists(DESTINATION_FILE.toPath());
    Files.deleteIfExists(DECRYPTED_FILE.toPath());

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    X509Certificate certificate = getX509Certificate(new File(WORK_DIR, "cert.cer"));
    encrypt(certificate, SOURCE_PDF, DESTINATION_FILE);
}

private static void encrypt(X509Certificate cert, File source, File destination) throws CertificateEncodingException, CMSException, IOException {
    CMSEnvelopedDataStreamGenerator gen = new CMSEnvelopedDataStreamGenerator();
    gen.addRecipientInfoGenerator(new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(cert));
    OutputEncryptor encryptor = new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.SHA256)
            .setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
            .build();

    try (FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(destination);
         OutputStream encryptingStream = gen.open(fileStream, encryptor)) {

        byte[] unencryptedContent = Files.readAllBytes(source.toPath());
        encryptingStream.write(unencryptedContent);
    }

    System.out.println(String.format("Encrypted '%s' to '%s'", source.getAbsolutePath(), destination.getAbsolutePath()));
}

private static X509Certificate getX509Certificate(File certificate) throws IOException, CertificateException {
    try (InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(certificate)) {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        return (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
    }
}
}
```

this code return exception on

```
OutputEncryptor encryptor = new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.SHA256)
            .setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
            .build();
```

->

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException: cannot create key generator: no such algorithm: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.3 for provider BC
at org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.EnvelopedDataHelper.createKeyGenerator(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder$CMSOutputEncryptor.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
at EncryptAndDecrypt.encrypt(EncryptAndDecrypt.java:66)
at EncryptAndDecrypt.main(EncryptAndDecrypt.java:42)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.3 for provider BC
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:87)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:97)
at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:265)
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.util.NamedJcaJceHelper.createKeyGenerator(Unknown Source)
... 5 more
```

and

code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PublicKey publicKey = getCert().getPublicKey();
        byte[] message = "Hello World".getBytes("UTF8");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(JCP.GOST_EL_DEGREE_NAME);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message);
    }
    public static Certificate getCert() {
        KeyStore trustStore  = null;
        try {
            trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null);//Make an empty store
            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("cert.cer");
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

            while (bis.available() > 0) {
                Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(bis);
                trustStore.setCertificateEntry("fiddler" + bis.available(), cert);
            }

            return trustStore.getCertificate("fiddler" + bis.available());
            //System.out.println(test);
            //System.out.println(test.getPublicKey());
        } catch (Exception ignored) {

        }

        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

This code return exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting GOST3410EL

and code

```
Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, Encrypt.getCert());
byte[] message = "Hello World".getBytes("UTF8");
byte[] encrypted = encryptCipher.doFinal(message);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(encrypted));
```

this code return exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: ru.CryptoPro.JCP.Key.GostPublicKey

Comment: Maybe instead of `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(JCP.GOST_EL_DEGREE_NAME);` use `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");`

Comment: cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA"); -> Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: ru.CryptoPro.JCP.Key.GostPublicKey

Comment: I am rusty on encryption. Look up "asymmetric encryption" on google and open the first few links. You will find the way that asymmetric encryption is used because the initializing and usage here do not look correct

Comment: You must register your crypto library before. There are few examples of how to do it for BouncyCastle.